# Create class User. Print the name of this User

Tags: java

> Create class User. The User class contains 2 fields:
>
> ● String name;
>
> ● int age;
>
> Create a list from User, Solve the following problem using StreamAPI: Find the first user in the list whose name starts with the letter “A”. Print the name of this User

My answer return me whole info but I need only name

```
public class User {

    String name;
    int age;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }

    public User(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<User> user = Arrays.asList(new User("Tom", 15),
                new User("Anna", 25),
                new User("Gerda", 20),
                new User("Alex", 33),
                new User("Annabel", 27)
        );

        Optional<User> userName = user.stream().filter(s -> s.getName().startsWith("A")).findFirst();
        System.out.printf("User name is: " + userName.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: `userName.get()` is the whole object. Try `userName.get().getName()`

Comment: It's working, thank you!

Comment: `user.stream().map(User::getName).filter(n -> n.startsWith("A")).findFirst().ifPresent(n -> System.out.printf("User name is: " + n));`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it will throw  NoSuchElementException if there no element in the list that start with A

Answer (score 1):

People have already given answers in the comments (ie you forgot `.getName()`), here are some other options

So now your solution should work but check the Optional first.

```
Optional<User> userOptional = user.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.getName().startsWith("A"))
        .findFirst();

if(userOptional.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println("User name is: " + userOptional.get().getName());
} else {
    System.out.println("No user name starting with A");
}
```

You could also get the name directly in the Optional:

```
Optional<String> userNameOptional = user.stream()
        .map(User::getName)
        .filter(name -> name.startsWith("A"))
        .findFirst();

if(userNameOptional.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println("User name is: " + userNameOptional.get());
} else {
    System.out.println("No user name starting with A");
}
```

Or you can even print it out directly

```
user.stream()
    .map(User::getName)
    .filter(name -> name.startsWith("A"))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresentOrElse(
            name -> System.out.println("User name is: " + name),
            () -> System.out.println("No user name starting with A"));
```